# Google maps api v3 get lat long from file with addresses in java code

Tags: google-maps-api-3, latitude-longitude, street-address

I am trying to make an application which draws a heatmap. I have a file with home addresses which I am going to put on the map. Every address is a new line in this file. 
I know how to create a heatmap layer when have coordinates.
What is the best way to get coordinates for these addresses?
I know there are couple ways of doing that, but the one that I am looking for is the way to do it on a server. I know that I have to send a request to the server. Can you please provide an example code in Java which gets a lat long coordinates for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this library:

http://code.google.com/p/geocoder-java/

It has documented examples as well.

Comment: Thanks for your help but the problem is that I saw this page. I am not sure how it works. That's why I am asking if somebody can share their code or give me a sample code how to send and receive request from Google